# Android AccountManagerFuture or onActivityResult callback

Tags: java, android, android-activity, future, accountmanager

I have been working with implementation of custom `AccountAuthenticator` for a server. Having the ability to provide a callback to the `AccountManager` is very convenient, as opposed to waiting on Activity result.

However, this has prompted me to think if it is possible to implement a similar flow in my application.

As far as I understood from reading through Android code, `AccountManagerFuture` relies on `AccountAuthenticatorResponse` (AAR) to resolve. That is, AAR is parcelable and gets passed around, from start Activity to the `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` (AAA). Upon success or error, AAA invokes a method of AAR, resolving or rejecting it. This is then communicated to the start Activity.

However, I am a little unclear on the point as to where the reference of original activity lives, how is memory leaking is avoided, and how is garbage collection is prevented.

From searching around, I saw several suggestions that allude to using a `Service` to keep the `Future` from being garbage collected and `WeakReference` to Activity/Callback from leaking memory. Yet, it is not quite clear and doesn't come all together in my head just yet.

I would appreciate if some of the senior Android developers could explain the cycle to me.

Here is what I understand (for reference, we'll take AccountManager's `addAccount` method):

- `addAccount` method is invoked with `Activity` and `AccountManagerCallback` provided
- AccountManager spawns a new FutureTask (`AmsTask`), which has a private member `Response`
- The response implements AIDL, which is used for inter-process communication (between AccountManager Service and originating Activity, I'm guessing)... so basically this already introduces a limitation where `AccountManager Service` and my Application are two processes. Whichever custom Service I spawn from my Application, it will still run under the same process, correct? Does this mean that we cannot reproduce this flow? One thought is that because `AccountAuthenticators` come from different Applications, which are in turn different processes/users, this needs to use AIDL. However, if my custom FutureTask and response is contained within one process, maybe regular Service will work.
- AccountManager Service gets binder from my `AccountAuthenticator` Service and invokes `addAccount`, passing in the response.
- I do my thing in the authenticator, spawning an activity, which then finishes and invokes `onResult` method, delivering results (How is memory leak avoided here, if originating Activity ends or gets recreated? Won't the callback then be invokes on an instance that is no longer active?)
- The `AccountManager Service` then propagates the response back to originating Activity (How is the originating activity not being garbage collected?)

Please provide your thoughts and clarifications. I'm sure there are plenty!